Is it possible to add SHA-512 integrity to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans and include it in Content-Security-Policy?
I’m trying to add an integrity hash to the https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans external stylesheet to secure it within my Content-Security-Policy (CSP), but I'm getting an error in the console.
Here’s what I have in my .aspx file:
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"  integrity="sha512-a3b5736eb509cf1f0ee024b8eae8eaedfa32121b268bc864ae93f456ad4236f3dc84ed942b7ee1fe7fe207d8643616fcbb68bcb1bf76ea6eb8f824e1900a2e25" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

And here’s the relevant section in my web.config file:
<add name="Content-Security-Policy"
                     value="default-src 'self'; 
                    style-src 'self' 'sha512-a3b5736eb509cf1f0ee024b8eae8eaedfa32121b268bc864ae93f456ad4236f3dc84ed942b7ee1fe7fe207d8643616fcbb68bcb1bf76ea6eb8f824e1900a2e25';
                    font-src 'self';" />

However, this setup throws the following console error:

Refused to load the stylesheet
'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"style-src 'self'
'sha512-a3b5736eb509cf1f0ee024b8eae8eaedfa32121b268bc864ae93f456ad4236f3dc84ed942b7ee1fe7fe207d8643616fcbb68bcb1bf76ea6eb8f824e1900a2e25'".
Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is
used as a fallback.

I understand that Google Fonts generates dynamic CSS that can’t always match a static hash.
Is there a way to use an integrity attribute with Google Fonts, or do I need to adjust the CSP differently to load this stylesheet securely? Any insights or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
